# trying to setAttribute to one item in an array with js, but DOM changes all

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
    var syncData = [
              {"end": "1.130","start": "0.849","text": "I'm" },
              {"end": "1.390","start": "1.140","text": "seeing" ,"class": "alert"},
              {"end": "4.009","start": "3.449","text": "something" }]
```

and I'm adding that class in "seeing" because I want to change that word's style in the transcript, synced up with the audio (see start and end times in seconds as the other fields in the array). That is, when "seeing" is spoken, I want the background to be highlighted.

I tried adding

```
    element.setAttribute("class", "alert");
```

but when I did that I saw in the DOM that everything had that class attributed to it. Here is the complete code, which currently highlights all the words, things I tried commented out:

```
    ( function(win, doc) {
        var audioPlayer = doc.getElementById("audiofile");
        var subtitles = doc.getElementById("subtitles");
        var syncData = [
             {"end": "1.130","start": "0.849","text": "I'm" },
              {"end": "1.390","start": "1.140","text": "seeing" ,"class": "alert"},
               {"end": "4.009","start": "3.449","text": "something" }

            ];
        createSubtitle();

        function createSubtitle()
        {
            var element;
            for (var i = 0; i < syncData.length; i++) {
                element = doc.createElement('span');
                element.setAttribute("id", "c_" + i);
                //element.setAttribute("class", "alert");
                element.innerText = syncData[i].text + " ";
                subtitles.appendChild(element);

            }

        audioPlayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e){
            syncData.forEach(function(element, index, array){

                 if( audioPlayer.currentTime >= element.start && audioPlayer.currentTime <= element.end )
                    subtitles.children[index].style.background = 'yellow';
                // var x = subtitles.children[index].getElementsByClassName("alert");
                // var j;
                // for (j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
                // if( audioPlayer.currentTime >= element.start && audioPlayer.currentTime <= element.end )
                //     x[j].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
                // else if (audioPlayer.currentTime > element.start && audioPlayer.currentTime > element.end )
                //     x[j].style.backgroundColor = 'DarkGrey'; }
                //if (audioPlayer.currentTime >= element.start && audioPlayer.currentTime <= element.end )
                    //subtitles.children[index].getElementsByClassName("alert").style.background = "yellow";
```

Comment: Where exactly is that line in your code? In the `for..i` loop? Or in the `forEach` loop?

Comment: I put it back in where it was, now commented out, in the for...i loop.

Comment: Like your line `element.innerText = syncData[i].text + " ";` you can add the class pulled from `syncData[i].class` but test first to see if there is one. `if (syncData[i].class) { element.classList.add(syncData[i].class); }` This _if_ tests for any _truthy_ value for class -- defined, non-null, not empty.

Comment: Thanks, this is adding the correct class into the DOM.I can't figure out why it isn't changing its color though.To experiment, I added another class to the other words called "reg", and then I modified the forEach loop thusly: `if( audioPlayer.currentTime >= element.start && audioPlayer.currentTime <= element.end )
                        subtitles.children[index].getElementsByClassName("reg")[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";` and then another one with else if for the "alert" class making that yellow. It doesn't throw errors but doesn't highlight.

Comment: Your new problem sounds like it's probably something to do with your CSS–it could be from a simple typo.  In any case, that is a new issue and should be a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < syncData.length; i++) {
  element = doc.createElement('span');
  element.setAttribute("id", "c_" + i);
  if(syncData[i].class) element.setAttribute("class", syncData[i].class); // see this line
  element.innerText = syncData[i].text + " ";
  subtitles.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. Now, the issue is that the styles still don't change, although the DOM has correct classes.